# ZOHO projects document API return empty response with status code 201(Created)

Tags: php, curl, zoho

I am trying to upload a document using the project API and it's giving an empty response with status 201. Due to an empty response, I am unable to get the id and name of the file uploaded.

```html
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $link,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('uploaddoc'=> new CURLFILE($path)),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
              'Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token,
              "Accept: application/json"
            ),
));
```

Link:

https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/documents-api.html#alink3